# Bootstrap - Sempre mostrar o side-bar

Tags: css3, bootstrap

Boa tarde, meus amigos.
Acabei de baixar um template bootstrap de Dashboard através desse [link](http://www.techfolks.net/10-free-bootstrap-admin-dashboard-templates-and-themes/), item 6.

Eu esperava que o menu lateral ficasse assim, sempre visível à esquerda:

[image: Eu esperava que o menu lateral ficasse assim, sempre visível à esquerda]

Porém ele veio oculto, tendo de clicar no botão para expandí-lo do lado direito.

Como ainda tô aprendendo a lidar com Bootstrap não sei o que devo editar para deixar do jeito que está na imagem. Se alguém puder baixar o template e me dar alguma dica, agradeço muito.

Fico à disposição para editar a pergunta e dispor mais detalhes.

Comment: Olá @JhonatanPereira. Se está aprendendo Bootstrap você pode começar entendendo o sistema de grids, dependências, layout, estilos e etc. E começar pelos templates mais básicos. Eu particularmente não gosto de usar esses templates semi prontos da internet, porquê vem com muitas coisas que não preciso, nomeação e estrutura mais complexa do que poderia ser, com mais estilos do que de fato seria necessário...

Comment: Entendi, o sistema de grid é bem fácil de entender, e realmente esses templates vêm sobrecarregados, mas eu vou limpar muita coisa..

Comment: Só recorri a isso porque preciso agilizar kk

Answer (score 0):

O tema dispunha de um menu de configurações onde eu escolhia onde queria o side-bar e outros elementos, sem mexer com código.